# Setting text from a google script into edittext

Tags: android, kotlin

I am currently making an app that can retrieve an IP address from a google link and will write the retrieved IP address into an EditText to automatically fill the text box for the user. However, I am unable to see that my text is in the EditText. I am writing this in Android Studio using Kotlin. the following is my code.

```
     val L1IPAdd: String = URL("myurl").readText()
     val IP1AddBox: EditText = findViewById(R.id.editTextNumber) //This is an EditText box on screen
     IP1AddBox.setText(L1IPAdd)
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong? I am new to learning coding in general, and any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
val L1IPAdd: String = URL("myurl").readText()
```

**this is giving you null, thats why you are getting an error!**

**try below code to check if your typecasting is okay or not, if its work fine then catch L1IPAdd rightly**

```
IP1AddBox.setText("Testing Text")
```

Comment: After reading your suggestion, I tested using 

IP1AddBox.setText("Testing Text")

but was unable to write into the editText as well.

Comment: Okay! is your typecasting is okay? if it it. then you are getting null value in your L1IPAdd

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean by that. If you are talking about the type of data that I get from the URL, Android Studio says that readText gives a String

Comment: Are You getting the readText value correctly?

Comment: Are you setting the text in the edit text on the main thread? This problem can be due to setting the text on a background thread.

Comment: I am writing the code in the main activity, so I believe it is on the main thread, but the typecasting is off because I am unable to write the test code into it also